# Subliminal does not work in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: python, 18.04, subliminal

Subliminal gives this error in Ubuntu 18.04

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/subliminal", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('subliminal==1.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'subliminal')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2693, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2324, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2330, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/subliminal/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .api import (ProviderPool, check_video, provider_manager, download_best_subtitles, download_subtitles,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/subliminal/api.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .subtitle import compute_score, get_subtitle_path
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/subliminal/subtitle.py", line 7, in <module>
    from guessit.matchtree import MatchTree
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/guessit/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from guessit.plugins import transformers
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/guessit/plugins/transformers.py", line 222, in <module>
    reload()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/guessit/plugins/transformers.py", line 220, in reload
    reload_options(all_transformers())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/guessit/plugins/transformers.py", line 179, in all_transformers
    return _extensions.objects()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/guessit/plugins/transformers.py", line 111, in objects
    return self.map(self._get_obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 261, in map
    raise NoMatches('No %s extensions found' % self.namespace)
stevedore.exception.NoMatches: No guessit.transformer extensions found
```

Output of apt-cache policy subliminal

```
  Installed: 1.1.1-2
  Candidate: 1.1.1-2
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.1-2 500
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy subliminal`

Comment: Nice, same problem in Wily =\

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer that works not only for Ubuntu 18.04, Bionic but also any release with `pip` installed

The problem appears to be an incompatibility between the latest python `stevedore` package and `guessit`, as reported in the [Debian Bug Report Logs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=881264)

The solution would be to install an appropriate version of `stevedore` from the [PyPi Repository](https://pypi.org/project/subliminal/), in order to do that

- Uninstall the existing packages that you've obtained from apt by using `sudo apt-get purge -y python3-stevedore`
- Install the PyPi version of subliminal with the appropriate version of stevedore by using `sudo pip3 install subliminal stevedore==1.19.1`

Now running `subliminal` from the terminal will let it run as usual:

[image: Subliminal on 18.04]

Answer (score 3):

`argparse` is now part of Python2 and Python3, but `subliminal` depends on `python3-stevedore` and this package contains the entry `argparse` in `requires.txt`. You can check this with:

- Vivid

  ```
  cat /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore-1.3.0.egg-info/requires.txt
  ```
- Wily

  ```
  cat /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore-1.5.0.egg-info/requires.txt
  ```

---

The solution is a dirty hack, remove the line:

- Vivid

  ```
  sudo sed -i.bak '/argparse/d' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore-1.3.0.egg-info/requires.txt
  ```
- Wily

  ```
  sudo sed -i.bak '/argparse/d' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore-1.5.0.egg-info/requires.txt
  ```

For Bionic (18.04) the above works but take into account the stevedore version is higher. It can be checked with:

ls -l /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/

and then search for the stevedore-* folder. In my case:

sudo sed -i.bak '/argparse/d' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/stevedore-1.28.0.egg-info/requires.txt

Comment: Is there a way to make this work in 18.04?

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
pip3 install --user subliminal stevedore==1.19.1
```

after installing subliminal via apt, in order to fix stevedore version. This will override the system version.